# Gmail Accessed by Remote Acess User in China, Computer, VNC number used

Tags: gmail

Recently, we received an email from a foreign exchange student we hosted (from China) with a video from the family that required us to download an app for translation. I downloaded the app via my Iphone. The app gained access to my Gmail account (or said it now had access to it as a regular user). Perhaps that was the dumbest thing I could have done.

Checking my Gmail from work, a notice popped up that my Gmail was being accessed by computer in China and showed the VPN that were being used, home and work computer as well as some locations in Alabama and North Carolina. I changed my Gmail password that was required when I download the app.

Would these be enough to keep that app from accessing my account? or gaining the VPN numbers of computers I used Gmail on?

Thanks!

Is a password change sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a password change would remove its access. You should go to your account settings and remove its access there.

https://myaccount.google.com/intro/security?utm_source=OGB&utm_medium=act#connectedapps

This link should be the right place.